# Show that $A$ is open in $\mathbb R$

Tags: real-analysis, general-topology

I got this question in a test earlier today. I know it is a very small question, since it only counted 2 marks, but for some reason I simply could not get it??

> Let $f:\mathbb R \to \mathbb R$ be continuous. Show that $A= \{x \in \mathbb R : -1 < f(x) < 1 \}$ is open in $\mathbb R$

Can anyone please explain to me how to go about answering this? So that I do not miss this again in future

Comment: Do you know that the preimage of an open set under a continuous function is an open set ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Maybe you've seen a theorem stating that the inverse image of an open subset by a continuous function is an open subset (this is actually a general definition for continuity) ?

Here, $A=f^{-1}((-1,1))$.

Comment: Oh my goodness!! Yes!!! I remember that theorem now ... If $f$ is continuous on $\mathbb R^p$, it equivalent to saying $f^{-1}(A)$ is open in $\mathbb R^p$ for each open set $A$ in \mathbb R^p .

Answer (score 1):

For all $ x \in A$ you have $-1 < \lim_{t \to x}f(t) <1$, so there exists some $\varepsilon > 0$ such that $(x-\varepsilon, x + \varepsilon) \subseteq A$.

This shows that $A$ is open.